# Is this possible to get the index of elements in a List in JSTL <c:if> tag

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, java-ee-6, jsp-tags

I am building a JSP which uses a list stored in request scope. There is a next button in JSP, initially the first element in the list will be used by the JSP when the jsp first shows up, when the next button is clicked, the second element in the list will be used, and so on. When the last element is used, the next button will not show up.

The pseudocode is like this, 
<c:if test = "{index != (fn:length(list) - 1)}"> 
     <button>Next<button>
</c:if>
the question now is is there a way to get the index in <c:if> ? if not, what would be a good way to implement this feature?

Comment: Can you try keeping the index variable also in request scope? You can track the index value as a hidden form field.

Comment: It works. Thanks Shankar.